# React js - mapping over multiple arrays to get one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have following code:

```
let getEntries = Object.entries(this.state.items).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    let pos = value[1].location;
    for (var lat in pos) {
      let lt = ${pos[lat]};
      this.setState({lat: this.state.lat.concat(lt)});
    };
    for (var lon in pos) {
      let ln = ${pos[lon]};
      this.setState({lon: this.state.lon.concat(ln)})
    };
    let latLng = this.state.lat.map((value,index)=>[parseFloat(value),parseFloat(this.state.lon[index])]);
    this.setState({latLng});
  });
```

If I `console.log` `latLng` state, I get following structure:

```
[
    [val1, val2]
    [val1, val2]
    [valN, valN]
]
```

As you can see, I get object values through looping over corresponding objects and then in `let latLng` I make these values to form a single array. It works how it suppossed to, but I also need some other data to be in that `latLng` array.
I got this data same way, just for example:

```
let getMessage = Object.entries(this.state.items).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    let value = value[1].message;
    for (var i in value) {
      let messages = value[i];
      this.setState({messages: this.state.messages.concat(messages)});
    }
  });
let getSomethingOther = Object.entries(this.state.items).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    let someValue = value[1].someProperty;
    for (var someProp in someValue) {
      let someOutput = someValue[someProp];
      this.setState({someState: this.state.someState.concat(someOutput)});
    }
  });
```

These functions work, but now I need to get them into my `latLng` array which I store in the state and can call it by using `this.state.latLng`. I think I'd need something like `map` function as in first example, but I can't get it working. Eventually I need such structure which I can use via my `this.state.latLng`:

```
[
   [val1, val2, val3, val4]
   [val1, val2, val3, val4]
   [val1, val2, val3, val4]
   [valN, valN, valN, valN]
]
```

How can I reach it in my case?

Comment: can you share sample data of `this.state.items`?

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul yes, it's an array of objects with different data and it looks like this:
`[name: "someName", data: []`. I don't need all the data, so I return only what I need.

Answer (score 0):

what I'm trying to do here is simplifying to help you what you want to achieve. Hope it helps

```
let getEntries = Object.entries(this.state.items).map(key, value) => {
    const latlon = this.state.latlng.concat([pos.lat, pos.lon])
    this.setState({ lat: this.state.lat.concat(pos.lat), lon: this.state.lon.concat(pos.lon) }, () => this.setState({ latlon }))
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the `flatMap()` function. Alas, I couldn't google-find it in reactjs. Maybe you can use this [pretty and minimal one-line Javascript implementation](https://gist.github.com/samgiles/762ee337dff48623e729)?